# MySQL query: Detect different rows between two tables and show differences in result table

Tags: mysql, join, query, subquery

I have two tables in a MySQL database.

```
Table1
a_id
1
3
4
5
6


Table2
b_id
1
2
3
```

I would like to spot the missing row from Table1 a_id 2, and missing rows from Table2 b_id 4,5,6, which should be shown in columns deleted_from_a, deleted_from_b with values 1.

```
Expected output:
+----+----+--------------+--------------+
|a_id|b_id|deleted_from_a|deleted_from_b|
|   1|   1|             0|             0|
|    |   2|             1|             0|
|   3|   3|             0|             0|
|   4|    |             0|             1|
|   5|    |             0|             1|
|   6|    |             0|             1|
+----+----+--------------+--------------+
```

How can I query the output result?

**EDIT1:**

Updated Table1, to have additional values compared to Table2.

**EDIT2:**

Updated the specification, it was not perfect at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Table1.a_id,
       Table2.b_id,
       Table1.a_id IS NULL deleted_from_a,
       Table2.b_id IS NULL deleted_from_b
FROM ( SELECT a_id AS id FROM Table1
       UNION
       SELECT b_id FROM Table2 ) total
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON total.id = Table1.a_id
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON total.id = Table2.b_id
ORDER BY total.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc08079c1868673e586f946d1f662fa0

---

> Is it possible to avoid nested subquery, just use joins? – klor

```sql
SELECT t1.id a_id, t2.id b_id, 0 deleted_from_a, t2.id IS NULL deleted_from_b
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t1.id IS NULL, 0 
FROM t2 
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
ORDER BY COALESCE(a_id, b_id)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c9d5378dbc4821b8e559003c73b62f8

Comment: Thanks! If there are additional values in Table1, which are missing from Table2, then those are missing from the output. See this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df2712babc2cfa35dbc95d7a398b7f92

Comment: @klor This is another task. You should have either specified this from the beginning or created another question.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. But I had to revise the specification in the meantime. I edited the OP.

Comment: @klor The answer altered.

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much! Is it possible to avoid nested subquery, just use joins?

Comment: @klor MySQL does not implement FULL JOIN. But yes, you may avoid a subquery. Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm grateful! Solution accepted.